# Flutter: Agora chat appkey is invalid Error

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am trying to create a chat app using Flutter and the Agora SDK. However, when I try to connect to the Agora server, I am getting the following error message: "Error code 100, appkey is invalid".

```
class AgoraChatConfig {
  static const String appKey = "b0fc8da1f9304*************";
  static const String userId = "user1";
  static const String agoraToken = "007eJxTYIjTYWrUqYlPTnX5GWRtvX....";
}
```

```
void _initSDK() async {
    ChatOptions options = ChatOptions(
      appKey: AgoraChatConfig.appKey,
      autoLogin: false,
    );
    await ChatClient.getInstance.init(options);
  }
```

```
void _signIn() async {
    try {
      await ChatClient.getInstance.loginWithAgoraToken(
        AgoraChatConfig.userId,
        AgoraChatConfig.agoraToken,
      );
      _addLogToConsole("login succeed, userId: ${AgoraChatConfig.userId}");
    } on ChatError catch (e) {
      _addLogToConsole("login failed, code: ${e.code}, desc: ${e.description}");
    }
  }
```

I have double-checked that I have entered the correct App ID and App Key in my code, and have verified that my Agora account has the necessary permissions to access the App ID and App Key. I have also checked that my network connection is stable and that no firewalls are blocking the connection. Despite these measures, I am still getting the error message.

Comment: Create a new project on agora coonsole and create new creadentials of Agora . Implement new credentials . Hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

You should enable chat feature firstly. enable link here: docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/get-started/enable?platform=android and Chat AppKey rule is ${OrgName}#{AppName} , not appid.

And here is the appkey.
[image]

Hope this helps.

if you still facing this issue, **just try reinstall app for deleting the app cache**.